# Swift/XCode 6.4: add back button to navigation controller in navigation bar

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, segue

In my app I have this storyboard:
[image]

and I would like to add a back button from the second table view back to the first. So I inserted a Navigation controller in order to have a navigation bar in the second table view ad I have created a segue with its identifier from the second table view to the first. But then how can I add a back button? I have tried to drag a button from the library into the navigation controller but it won't let me do it...I had already done this but in this moment I can't remember how.
Please can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]In above image you shared you are making your tableview controller as root view controller.You have to kept your navigation controller on root. As you can see in attached image and you don't have to make back button manually as navigation controller has its own default back button.

Answer (score 1):

This example is right how to make storyboard.Try it

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.hidden = false
```

[image]

In setting of `UINavigationController` set up like on screenshot

[image]

Comment: Ok, I've just done as the picture shows...But I still don't see back buttons when the simulator is launched. I don't really know where I am making the mistake...maybe in the segues? :(

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a navigation controller and its default navigation bar, you don't add an explicit back button--the navigation bar does it for you. You can add a `UINavigationItem` to your view controller, on which you set a title, back button title, etc.

Comment: Really the back button is added by the navigation controller by default? Because I can't see it in the

Comment: Can't see it in the what? It will appear at runtime as soon as you transition to a second scene.

Comment: Really the back button is added by the navigation controller by default? Because I can't see it in the second table view...maybe I have made a mess with the navigation controller...I'll try to add a new one...

Comment: Wait--let me clarify. It will add a default back button *if the scene has been pushed onto the navigation controller*, not if it's a modal. The segue type that I see in your storyboard is not a push.

Comment: And one more thing--do not add an explicit segue from your second table view controller back to the first one. Instead, investigate unwind segues.

Comment: Ok, in this moment I'm not at home, I'll try as soon as I'm back. So I should choose the type of segue as "push", right?

Comment: Forgive but I don't know many things about segue and xcode in general...it's all new to me and I'm findinf many difficulties...